# Oracle 11g connection error in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

have installed oracle 11g on win 10, 64 bit.
SQL Plus is working very nice but Oracle Developer connection is not getting success. Can anybody help me ?

[image]

Comment: For starters, set role from SYSDBA to normal

Comment: Thanks dear.  i tried but still its not working. Is there any other idea ?

Answer (score 2):

"Got minus one" often means you are connecting to the wrong port. 1158 is the port often used for the database console (which is http/https) and not the port you want to be using for SQL Dev.

Try 1521 (which is the default).

Comment: nice catch eagle-eye!

Comment: Thanks Conneor but its not working its showing error msg like           "Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"                 and the thing is that during setup in database configuration Assistant window it was showing me port 1158. i have taken snapshot also of that window. is there any other way if you know.......

Comment: you're asking the listener on your machine to connect to data 'Ved' and the listener is saying, we don't know that database. Either the listener isn't configured correctly, or you have the name wrong